# Reading data from firebase everytime button is clicked, without having to refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, addeventlistener

I am quite the beginner in programming with web applications. My goal is to receive data from realtime firebase database.
So I have this code to read from realtime firebase application. When I do this I can actually see the output. My problem is that if I change a value in the input-box and submit again without reloading page, the javascript will not run the new input value.

[image]

For the console output in internet:
[image]

The problem is here, if I change value to "1" in input box without refreshing page, my program won't take that input and do stuff with it. Check below:
[image]

It's suppose to return a value of 0 and where i marked with circle it should say "1". If i refresh page and then put in 1 into input box, it works fine. But if I change back to 2 without refreshing. same problem.

I just want to do the same without user having to refresh page eveyrtime they type in new data.
Hope someone out there can help :) I watched so many tutorials for reading from database and I can't figure out what to do here.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share pictures of code and text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oninput` JS event to capture a value when it is changed

```js
var standNr = document.getElementById("standNr");
standNr.oninput = function() {
  console.log(standNr.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="standNr"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
defineStand.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    var stand_number = document.getElementById("standnr").value
    var dbRef = database.ref('stand/' + stand_number + '/status')
    
    e.preventDefault()

    dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
    
    console.log(stand_number)
    console.log(dbRef)
})
```

I solved it now. Works perfectly :D
My issue was that e.preventDefault wasn't placed after definings the variables :)

[image]